# How to copy specific parts of a table from a sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to get some details copied in Excel from Sheet 1 columns 1-5 to Sheet 2 columns 1-4, but only for lines that include text or values on sheet one under a specific column (in this case, Column 2). There are other columns in between, so I need to be able to use exact columns rather than A:D for example. 
Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Excel screenshot of dummy data]

I have tried using a simple IF function with A:A<>"" so it would include any rows that have any data in them, however this does not seem to copy as I need and occasionally based on my attempts i also get circular reference errors.  Additionally, I’m not sure how to make sure this gets pasted at the bottom of a table that will expand with each addition.

I realize a probably easier option would be to simply copy Sheet 1 entirely and use a filter on row 1 to deselect Blanks on A:A, but the sheet has so much more info that it would be a waste, and additionally info is constantly added so I need something scale-able. It also occurred to me now that by doing this i would include info from the "header" and "footer", basically a frozen pane - which I do not need.

Could this be done via a simple function, or would it require a Macro?

Please keep in mind I'm rubbish at programming, just trying to make my life easier and learn as I go. A lot of excel forums help but still I'm no coder. I can understand to a pretty big degree what the code does and can adjust accordingly though :)

Comment: It cannot be done with a forumla. But [you can use a simple filter (autofilter)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-autofilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and filter only the data that has data in columns A, B, D and E. That's easily done with filter tools provided in the "Data" tab of the ribbon. If you need to do it with VBA record a macro. • If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question to it.

Comment: I can probably do it with autofilter, but then i'd need to go back an remove the filter after copying the data to the new sheet, which isn't ideal. that still leaves me with the issue of how to paste at the bottom of an expanding table via VBA?

Comment: By a formula, no way. Go by macro. Just to not to make it hard for you... use the Macro Recorder in order to do what you are trying. With your knowledge, try to reduce/custom the code as much as you can and, when you get stuck, we will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, this cannot be done with formulas. There are different ways to achieve this.. below is one approach:

```
Sub CopyFilteredRows()
    Dim oSourceSheet As Worksheet: Set oSourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")             ' Set your source sheet here
    Dim oRng As Range: Set oRng = oSourceSheet.Range("A2:E" & oSourceSheet.Range("C" & oSourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Set filter on column B
    oRng.AutoFilter
    oRng.AutoFilter 2, "<>"
    
    ' Copy to specified sheet
    oRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")   ' Change your destination sheet here
    
    ' Clear objects
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oSourceSheet = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Paste the above UDF in a Module and then run it whenever you want to perform the copy. I suspect you would have to modify it a bit so that you can cater for your particular scenario but it should give you a start

Comment: Thanks so much Zac, this seems to do the trick and i tested adding more lines and works fine. By the looks of it it copies everything, so might become a bit slow once i get to 5-800 lines, but not to worry for now.

LE: I added the blow code
 `Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter`

To deselect the filter at the end so Sheet 1 displays full info again. Out of curiosity, what does your Clear Objects part do?

Comment: @ciuncky It doesn't change anything. Because the variables are declared within the scope of your procedure, the variables are cleared with `End Sub` automatically anyway. You don't need these 2 lines and can remove them savely to keep your code cleaner.

Comment: As @Pᴇʜ said, **Clear objects** bit is not needed.. old habits really. All it does is clear the objects from the memory but as mentioned, once the UDF completes, they are cleared anyway so you can eliminate that part of the code and it wont make any difference